# ICommand WPF вызывается при запуске программы

Tags: c#, wpf

Рисую UI с помощью WPF и MVVM.
При использовании

```
  <Button Name="priceButton" Content="Прайс" Command="{Binding GetPricesCom}" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="339,513,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
  Width="125" Height="31" Click="priceButton_Click"/>
```

Метод вызывается при запуске программы, а не при нажатии кнопки. Каким образом реализовать ICommand, чтобы он вызывался только при нажатии кнопки.

```
    public ICommand GetPricesCom
    {
        get {
            GetPrices();
            return GetPricesCom;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Margin - не ставьте элементы руками в конструкторе, учите XAML разметку и пишите все сами (а то потом будете задавать вопрос "что у меня элементы скачут/пропадают"). Сам Margin должен быть не выше 15-20, а не 339... 2. Логика ICommand реализуется не в его get, а в отдельном методе, который через RelayCommand задается этому интерфейсу. 3. Click и Command на одном контроле... Вы серьезно?

Comment: С WPF столкнулся впервые, XAML тоже изучать не доводилось. Буду благодарен, если посоветуете качественную литературу по нему.

Comment: Могли бы и [поискать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-c/416585#416585)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим у вас есть кнопка

```
<Button Content="Test" Margin="5" Command="{Binding TestCommand}">
```

Далее, в вашей `ViewModel` вы создаёте команду. Я использую такое решение:

Это базовый класс для команд, давно нашёл его и теперь он кочует из проекта в проект.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

И в `ViewModel` объявляете команду

```
public RelayCommand TestCommand => new RelayCommand(o =>
{
    //Логика команды
});
```